# Source code of image with unicode

Tags: image, unicode, byte

(Only understandable if you're using Chrome)

Whenever I try to press Ctrl+U on an image page, nothing happens. So, I manually typed in the search bar "view-source:http://assets.silverdroid.ga/assets/discord/stop2.gif" and there, I found some very strange unicode characters, none of them readable.

Can someone explain to me what this is?
[Linked screenshot of "image code".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YBIK.png)

Comment: What did you expect to see?

Answer (score 2):

That's the image data of the GIF. You can see that it starts with "GIF89a", which [is a GIF format](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif89a.txt)

Basically what you are seeing is the binary data of the image displayed as characters, that's why most of them are "weird" or non-readable.